# Inner join where not

Tags: mysql

I have my main table with the following structure:

```
id | created_at          | f1_id | f2_id
1    2016-01-23 11:41:21   5       7
2    2016-01-23 12:31:22   5       7
```

Then I have a table 1:n to the previous table:

```
main_id | value
1         aaa
1         bbb
2         ccc
```

And then I have a table 1:1 to the previous one with confirmations:

```
f1_id | f2_id | value | confirmed_at
5       7       aaa     2016-01-25 21:41:51
9       9       ccc     2016-01-25 23:51:45
```

Now I want to get all NOT confirmed values from the date range from the main table. How do I find all not confirmed values from range from the main table?

f1 and f2 are 1:1 tables used in the main table and confirmed values.

```
SELECT *
FROM maintable m
INNER JOIN f1table f1 ON m.f1_id = f1.id
INNER JOIN f2table f2 ON m.f2_id = f2.id
INNER JOIN values v ON m.id = v.main_id
INNER JOIN confirmed c ON (v.value = c.value AND c.f1_id = m.f1_id AND c.f2_id = m.f2_id)
WHERE m.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-20' AND '2016-01-24';
```

This SQL will fetch all confirmed values...but what about not confirmed?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you exactly want in your query?

Comment: You describe 3 tables, but your sample query has 5 tables: maintable, f1table, f2table, values, and confirmed. Please name the tables as you describe them, add descriptions for missing tables, and/or fix the example query, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an *anti-join* pattern.  Use an outer join to return all rows from one table. The outer join will return matching rows from the second table, but will also return rows from the first table that do *not* have a matching row. The trick is a predicate (condition) in the `WHERE` clause that excludes the rows that had a match, leaving only those rows that didn't have a match.

Based on your query, to return all rows from `m`, `v`, `f1` and `f2` where there isn't a matching row found in `c`, something like this:

```
SELECT m.id
     , m.created_at
     , m.f1_id
     , m.f2_id
     , v.main_id
     , v.value
  FROM maintable m
  JOIN f1table f1 ON m.f1_id = f1.id
  JOIN f2table f2 ON m.f2_id = f2.id
  JOIN values v ON m.id = v.main_id

  LEFT
  JOIN confirmed c
    ON c.value = v.value
   AND c.f1_id = m.f1_id
   AND c.f2_id = m.f2_id
 WHERE c.f1_id IS NULL

   AND m.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-20' AND '2016-01-24'
```

Any row from `c` that "matches" is going to have non-NULL values for the columns evaluated in the join condition (i.e. a NULL value in `c.f1_id` isn't going to satisfy the equality comparison.) So we can test for a non-NULL value in that column to identify which rows matched.

---

The specification is a little ambiguous, as to whether you would expect there to be rows from `f1` and/or `f2` when a matching row doesn't exist in `confirmed`. It's possible to use outer join operations to the `f1` and `f2` tables (add the `LEFT` keyword before `JOIN`.)

The *anti-join pattern* is easier to understand in a less complicated example. To return rows from `a` for which a matching row doesn't exist in `b`

```
SELECT a.foo
  FROM a
  LEFT
  JOIN b
    ON b.foo = a.foo
 WHERE b.foo IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the INNER JOIN to the `confirmed` table with a `NOT EXISTS` where-clause. Something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM maintable m
INNER JOIN f1table f1 ON m.f1_id = f1.id
INNER JOIN f2table f2 ON m.f2_id = f2.id
INNER JOIN values v ON m.id = v.main_id
WHERE m.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-20' AND '2016-01-24'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM confirmed c WHERE v.value = c.value AND c.f1_id = m.f1_id AND c.f2_id = m.f2_id)
```